# Highlighting search terms with Tipue after one has clicked on the link(s) displayed on result page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I have implemented the Tipue site search engine on my website according to their [documentation](http://www.tipue.com/search/docs/). I am using 'Live Mode' and everything works fine so far.

However, I was wondering if there is a way to highlight the input search terms after I have clicked on the link(s) that are displayed on the results page?

To specify, here is what I want to achieve:

1. User enters search term
2. Tipue does the search and displays results on 'results page' - here the search terms are highlighted
3. Upon clicking on one of the search results I want the search term highlighted on that page too

I am not exactly a jQuery/JavaScript wizard so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far:

**HTML** (allstudies.html - site that has been indexed by Tipue):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <!-- Link required to be in head for Tipue Search -->

  <link href="Tipue Search 5.0/tipuesearch/tipuesearch.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      #navbar stuff
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="searchbar">
    <form action="search.html">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="tipue_search_input" autocomplete="off" required>
    </form>

  </div>

  <div class="allstudies">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <h5>2016</h5>
            <li><a href="Validation Studies\2016\PDFs\Whey Concentrate, Dairy Liquids (retained sample) - DAIRY & FOOD INGREDIENTS & RENDERING AGENTS - 2016.pdf">Whey Concentrate, Dairy Liquids (retained sample) - DAIRY & FOOD INGREDIENTS & RENDERING AGENTS - 2016</a></li>
            #more items
            <h5>2015</h5>
            <li><a href="Validation Studies\2015\PDFs\Cocoa Powder - FOOD INGREDIENTS - 2015.pdf">Cocoa Powder - FOOD INGREDIENTS & RENDERING AGENTS - 2015</a></li>
            #more items, etc.
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**HTML** (search.html - site that displays the search results):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="Tipue Search 5.0/tipuesearch/tipuesearch.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Tipue Search 5.0/tipuesearch/tipuesearch_set.js"></script>
    <script src="Tipue Search 5.0/tipuesearch/tipuesearch.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
    <form action="search.html">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="tipue_search_input" autocomplete="off" required>
    </form> 
    <div id="tipue_search_content"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tipue_search_input').tipuesearch({
                'mode': 'live',
                'liveDescription': 'href',
                'liveContent': '*',
                'highlightEveryTerm': true
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in touch with the developer team at Tipue. Currently, the highlighting of search terms after one has clicked on the link(s) is not supported. (5th May 2016)

[image]